# Should I download Java's tar.gz or rpm to do offline java installation?

Tags: installation, java

I am going to download & install java on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32-bit system)

On java download page, there are 2 download options.

1. Java for Linux Platforms
2. Java for RPM based Linux Platforms

Which would be better suited for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

RPM is Redhat, Fedore, CentOS so unusable.

You need, preferably, a DEB version or otherwise the tar.gz version.

I would advicw to use a personal archive as explained here:http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-debian.html

Install method for java 7:

```
su -
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886
apt-get update
apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
exit
```

You can then install this...

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default
```

"To automatically set up the Java 7 environment variables"

Comment: Thanks. But I wish to get an installer package for offline installing, instead of every time downloading from the web.

Comment: @Vineet I wouldn't do that since Java has several release/year (if not months) to fix security vulnerabilities. If you have internet access where you need Java, the best option is using the repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Java for Linux Platforms. Here are the download instructions
There is a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-jdk-7) on how to install JDK 7

### Install the JRE

[Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) the 32bit or 64bit Linux "compressed binary file" - it has a ".tar.gz" file extension and uncompress it

```
tar -xvf jre-7-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

JRE 7 package is extracted into ./jre1.7.0 directory. Now move the JRE 7 directory to `/usr/lib`

```
sudo mv ./jre1.7.0* /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0
```

Afterwards run the following to get a list of currently installed java alternatives

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

You will get output as:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection Path Priority Status
————————————————————
* 0 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java 1061 auto mode
1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java 1061 manual mode
2 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java 63 manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Remember the last number and press enter to exit this utility i.e. in this example remember the number `2`.

If only one alternative is shown then remember the number `0`

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/bin/java 3
```

This will add your new JRE 7 installation into alternatives list i.e. use the remembered number + 1 i.e. 3 in the example above. Now configure java to use the Oracle Java JRE

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

You will see output similar one below - choose the number of jre1.7.0 i.e. `3`:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection Path Priority Status
————————————————————
* 0 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java 1061 auto mode
1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java 1061 manual mode
2 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java 63 manual mode
3 /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/jre/bin/java 3 manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode.
```

N.B. if there was no previous java installation then the new JRE will be the default and you will not see the above.

Check the version of you new JRE 7 installation:

```
java -version
```

Should produce

```
java version “1.7.0”
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

### [Install the Firefox/Chrome plugin](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java)

In a terminal:

```
mkdir ~/.mozilla/plugins
```

Remove the IcedTea plugin, if it has been installed.

```
sudo apt-get remove icedtea6-plugin
```

Remove a former version of the Java plugin (may or may not be present)

```
rm ~/.mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```

Now you can install the plugin, by creating a symbolic link (you tell Firefox, where the plugin is located). For 32bit java use

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/
```

For 64bit java use

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/
```

Confirm that the JRE has been successful by using the [official oracle website](http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp).

SOURCE: [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk)

Comment: Awesome comment about update-alternatives. This answer deserves way more points than it has.

Comment: If you want to install a JDK, take note of http://askubuntu.com/questions/315646/update-java-alternatives-vs-update-alternatives-config-java