# Setting java path in maven

Tags: java, environment-variables

When I do `mvn --v`, I get:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_45, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.16.0-30-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

When I do `java -version`, I get:

```
java version "1.7.0_76"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_76-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.76-b04, mixed mode)
```

Now I want maven to use java 7, how do I make this so?

Answer (score 8):

Firstly I opened Ubuntu Software center and searched for jdk removed the installer and default jdk 6 from there. Then I run the command :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

And selected the openjdk-7 from there. But when I run :

```
mvn --v
```

it said that JAVA_HOME is not set. Then did the following steps:

```
sudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Added the following lines at the end of the file :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Then close the gedit. And run the command :

```
source /etc/bash.bashrc
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Path was set.
And now :

```
mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_76, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.16.0-30-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: Also see this Answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/315646/update-java-alternatives-vs-update-alternatives-config-java/388693#388693
You can use `update-java-alternatives` to update both compiler and runtime

Answer (score 3):

To set the JAVA_HOME variable for only maven you can override your defaults by setting it in your `$HOME/.mavenrc` file.

The `$HOME/.mavenrc` is sourced by the `mvn` script. 
This is useful if you want to switch jvm for different projects.

This is the content of my `$HOME/.mavenrc` file:

```
#export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
#export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

This way i can comment out the jvm i want to use before i run maven.

Comment: If that file doesn't exists, create it. Maven will pick the content automatically

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation on [Ubuntu Environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

What we want to do here is persist our ***JAVA_HOME*** path.

Most commonly, our java installations go in ***/usr/lib/jvm***. To list the installations present,

```
ls /usr/lib/jvm
```

I have ***/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64*** among them and that is installation I want to use for maven.

We can add our entry for **JAVA_HOME** entry to **~/.pam_environment** and make it DEFAULT or OVERRIDE - that's your call.

Use whatever text editor you want to open the file (I am using a text editor that is lying around in my system - it's name is xed. You may use gedit or vim or anything)

```
xed ~/.pam_environment
```

You will find things like:

[image]

Now, let us add a new entry for our ***JAVA_HOME*** environment variable. In a new line, enter:

```
JAVA_HOME   DEFAULT=<your path to your java home location>
```

or

```
JAVA_HOME   DEFAULT=${JAVA_HOME}    OVERRIDE=<path to your java home location>
```

As my java home location is '*/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64*', I am entering 
`JAVA_HOME   DEFAULT=${JAVA_HOME}    OVERRIDE=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`

> Now, log out of your system and log back in for the change to take
>   effect.

Let's check the maven version now.

```
mvn -version
```

and it should work :
[image]