# Assistive technology not found AWTError

Tags: gnome, system-installation, java, accessibility, jar

```
$ java -jar aprof-plot.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadAssistiveTechnologies(Toolkit.java:807)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:886)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1734)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(EventQueue.java:1264)
    at aprofplot.Main.newWindow(Main.java:33)
    at aprofplot.Main.main(Main.java:359)
```

Possible explanations I saw here was to install Java-access-bridge. But I am unable to install `libaccess-java-bridge`.

Answer (score 199):

I ran into this same error on my Ubuntu 15.10 server but did not want to install the non-headless version of OpenJDK due to the number of additional dependencies. A simpler solution was to simply disable assistive technologies.

This can be done by editing the `accessibility.properties` file for OpenJDK 8 (change the version to whichever is actually in use on your system):

```
sudo vim /etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties
```

Comment out the following line:

```
#assistive_technologies=org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
```

---

Also you can edit this line programmatically:

```
sudo sed -i -e '/^assistive_technologies=/s/^/#/' /etc/java-*-openjdk/accessibility.properties
```

Comment: This is the best solution. Works for android-sdk/tools/draw9patch too (Android SDK Tools)

Comment: This also worked on my Ubntu 15.10 for fixing `freemind` that wasn't starting otherwise

Comment: it just happened to me today, two and half years after this answer. instead of java-8 it is java-11 now, other than that, helped me, thank you

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me for starting another software called OpenRefine. java-11-openjdk here as well.

Comment: Worked like a charm, just making some adjustments. It's not java-8 here.

Comment: Worked for fixing Slick2D game engine problem, thanks!

Comment: Also in __Ubuntu 20.10__   ;-)

Comment: Although my system is headless, my application does manipulate image files.  I do not want to install the full JRE which causes X to be installed.  I also do not want to disable the feature because I need to manipulate the image files.  So, the question is, if I disable the feature as you describe, will that inhibit the file image functionality of my application?

Answer (score 39):

Read the following thread. I managed to escape this problem by uninstalling OpenJDK 8 headless and installing OpenJDK 8.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=798794

Commands I ran:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep openjdk
```

This is to verify you are actually running the headless version of JAVA, so no graph library available.

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

This is to remove headless version.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

This is to install non-headless version of java.

Comment: This did the trick

Comment: proper solution

Answer (score 14):

For those who do not have root access on their machines to change the configuration file or do not want to install the full JRE: append `-Djavax.accessibility.assistive_technologies=" "` to your command, e.g.

```
$ java -jar aprof-plot.jar -Djavax.accessibility.assistive_technologies=" "
```

Do note that the `" "` is important, simply using "nothing" as parameter will cause the JRE to still load whatever is set in `/etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties`.

Comment: Appending did not solve for me. Prepending changed the message to `Assistive Technology not found: `  not followed by `org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper`.

Comment: This worked for me with Ubuntu 18.04 when java set back to version 8 from 10 (because openjfx not available precompiled yet). Other methods listed in this question did not work for me.

Answer (score 7):

Same issue. In my case I couldn't run FastQC.
This is what I did:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove openjdk-11-jre-headless
```

I verified java was gone

```
$ java -version
bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

I had to uninstall openjdk-11-jre, eg:

```
sudo apt remove openjdk-11-jre
```

or

```
sudo apt remove openjdk-11*
```

to remove all openjdk-11 packages on your system.

This forces your program to run on openjdk-8-jre instead of openjdk-11-jre, as I had both installed. Apparently Java Assistive Technology doesn't run on the openjdk-11-jre package. I believe there is also a way to specify which Java version to run, but I don't know it off the top of my head and I'm sure there's another post on that topic.

Comment: You don't even need to uninstall openjdk-11-jdk or openjdk-11-jre: https://askubuntu.com/questions/315646/update-java-alternatives-vs-update-alternatives-config-java

Answer (score 3):

Inspired from Marco's answer, but for me it only works in this order (prepending):

```
java -Djavax.accessibility.assistive_technologies=" " -jar aprof-plot.jar
```

It solved the problem and the program launched successfully (in my case argouml.jar fakesmtp.jar).

Using Java 8 on Ubuntu 2019.04

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error happens when you have a headless version of the JRE installed. The headless JRE is a subset of the full JRE but lacks GUI features, including support for assistive technologoes.

Install the full JRE (e.g. `openjdk11-jre` instead of `openjdk11-jre-headless`) and the error should go away. No need to uninstall the headless JRE.