# Can't run Java applications (like logisim) due to "Assistive Technology not found" error

Tags: lubuntu, java

I tried it and the errors are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.newAWTError(Toolkit.java:472)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.fallbackToLoadClassForAT(Toolkit.java:488)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1608)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadAssistiveTechnologies(Toolkit.java:532)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:613)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName(UIManager.java:660)
at com.cburch.logisim.gui.start.Startup.parseArgs(Startup.java:250)
at com.cburch.logisim.Main.main(Main.java:32)
```

The error seems to be...

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
>       at  java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
>       at   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:374)
>       at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.fallbackToLoadClassForAT(Toolkit.java:485)
>       ... 14 more

OUTPUT for  apt-cache policy logicsim logisim

```
logisim:
  Installed: 2.7.1~dfsg-1
  Candidate: 2.7.1~dfsg-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.1~dfsg-1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
N: Unable to locate package logicsim
```

OUTPUT for update-java-alternatives -l

```
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1101       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? How we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @N0bert it's the latest version. I just used : [sudo apt-get install logicsim] to install the app and when I try to start it I get the error.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy logicsim logisim` and `update-java-alternatives -l` to the question.

Comment: Problem fixed by disabling assistive technologies. See answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assistive technology not found AWTError](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695560/assistive-technology-not-found-awterror)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can confirm your issue on clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
So I reported [bug 1788267](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/logisim/+bug/1788267)  to the LaunchPad (currently it is marked as duplicate of [bug 1788250](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-lts/+bug/1788250) and exists in Debian too as [bug 900912](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=900912)).

It is unbelievable - many Java applications are broken and show the same error involving `java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper`.

**Update 20180913** - [bug is fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-lts/+bug/1788250/comments/16). Steps below are not needed (they are included in the updated package).

---

But we can fix this problem by disabling Assistive Techonologies inside `/etc/java-11-openjdk/accessibility.properties`:

```
sudo sed -i "s/^assistive_technologies=/#&/" \
/etc/java-11-openjdk/accessibility.properties
```

and/or inside `/etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties`

```
sudo sed -i "s/^assistive_technologies=/#&/" \
/etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties
```