# Java not opening programes ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, java

I recently upgraded my ubuntu sony vaio laptop from 16.04 to 18.04 and now that this has been completed I can't seem to open an important marking programme that I use to mark and return student work. The software in question is written for my university in java code to enable it to run on any operating system. I have previously opened the software up in Java 7 and Java 8 using previous versions of ubuntu. I have not experienced this problem before and was surprised. I need a solution urgently and would be most grateful for any suggestions. Thank you.

My sony viao specs are: 
Memory 2.0 GiB
Intel® Core™2 CPU T7200 @ 2.00GHz × 2
Intel® 945GM x86/MMX/SSE2
GNOME 3.28.2 
OS type 32-bit
Disk 310.8 GB

Error message when opening java file in terminal with `/home/sabirah/Desktop/etmaHandlerJLinux/etmaHandlerJLinux` as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.newAWTError(Toolkit.java:472)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.fallbackToLoadClassForAT(Toolkit.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1608)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadAssistiveTechnologies(Toolkit.java:532)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:613)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1494)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(EventQueue.java:1312)
    at etmaHandler.EtmaHandlerJ.main(EtmaHandlerJ.java:11417)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:374)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.fallbackToLoadClassForAT(Toolkit.java:485)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Please start application from terminal and add error output to the question.

Comment: OK good idea - but how do I start an application in terminal? What command line do I need and how do I select an application location that is located within a file that is on the desktop? Please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Make right click on desktop shortcut, view its properties (on GNOME with `<Ctrl+i>`). Then copy value of *Command* to the terminal. Or view shortcut with text editor (you need `Exec` field).

Comment: /home/sabirah/Desktop/etmaHandlerJLinux is the location. How do I ask termial to run the software? Is is something I need sudo apt-get powers for? Do I type sudo apt-get run /home/sabirah/Desktop/etmaHandlerJLinux   ?

Comment: apt-get is not related to current problem. Open terminal and execute `/home/sabirah/Desktop/etmaHandlerJLinux` in it by simple copy and paste.

Comment: I did this and get following in terminal: bash: /home/sabirah/Desktop/etmaHandlerJLinux: Is a directory

Comment: Then you incorrectly read *Command* field of desktop file. You need to get full executable path and copy it exactly to the terminal. It may consist of two parts - directory `/home/sabirah/Desktop/etmaHandlerJLinux` and name of executable file or script (something like `runme.sh`). So in my notation you need to run `/home/sabirah/Desktop/etmaHandlerJLinux/runme.sh` from terminal (change `runme.sh` to correct file-name).

Comment: Not sure how to do this. I followed your instructions and copied the exact location from properties. This is the location of the java file that will not open: /home/sabirah/Desktop/etmaHandlerJLinux. Sorry did not see rest of your comment. Will try the runme.sh bit and get back to you. Thank you : O ). Ok I tried with rume.sh and it did not recognise directory. How do I work out the correct file-name?

Comment: Please add output of the `grep -ir etmaHandlerJLinux ~/Desktop` command to the question.

Comment: OK I got there by copying the file name at the end of the location in terminal. I typed into terminal the following command: /home/sabirah/Desktop/etmaHandlerJLinux/etmaHandlerJLinux Then terminal came back with the following error message: sabirah@zurisuri:~$ /home/sabirah/Desktop/etmaHandlerJLinux/etmaHandlerJ.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
 at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.newAWTError(Toolkit.java:472)
 at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.fallbackToLoadClassForAT(Toolkit.java:488)

Comment: Got it. This is what I supposed. Possible duplicate of [Can't run Java applications (like logisim) due to "Assistive Technology not found" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067569/cant-run-java-applications-like-logisim-due-to-assistive-technology-not-foun)

Comment: Well thank you for all your help and patience! At least we know why it is not working! : O )

Comment: You can fix it  with commands from [duplicate answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1067607/66509). Currently many Java applications are broken this way.

Comment: Thank you so much Norbert. I see you had some similar issues yourself and solved them! I will try your solution. Fingers crossed! : O )