# I received an error fetching bootstrap, SSLHandshakeException : handshake_failure running runelite on lubuntu

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, java, jar

I received the following error whilst trying to launch a RuneLite jar on a freshly installed Lubuntu(18.10 64bit):

> [main] ERROR net.runelite.launcher.Launcher -error fetching bootstrap
>
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_faiure at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)

I'm assuming I need to install something or adjust a setting as runelite worked perfectly on a Ubuntu installation.

Comment: which java version do you use? `java -version` also what keystore is that java using? does the keystore trust the cert you try to connect to?

Comment: @TiloBunt `java -version` gives the following result: 
>openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.1+13-Ubuntu-2ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.1+13-Ubuntu-2ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: @TiloBunt I opened the cacerts file located in the java security folder using Portecle and it contains a lot of certificates. I don't know how to see which one would be for RuneLite.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I received that error because I had installed Java 11 which isn't compatible with RuneLite. Therefore I had to downgrade to Java version 8 after which another error occured which was solved by the answer on this link: [Assistive technology not found AWTError](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695560/assistive-technology-not-found-awterror). Thank you all for your efforts.