# Minecraft 1.8.9 Won't launch even when changed Java version to 8

Tags: java, launcher, openjdk, minecraft

I recently switched to Ubuntu, and I'm new to Linux.
I want to play Minecraft on version 1.8.9 on my Ubuntu machine.

I heard that you need to set your java to version 8, so I did that, and now the result of `java -version` is:

```
marzeq@marzeq-Aspire-VX5-591G:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~20.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)
```

as expected.

Also just for good measures I set the Java executable path in the Launcher to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`.

But the game still crashes with the exit code 0.

The weirder thing is that the vanilla version won't even give a log, so I need to use the Forge Mod Loader to even see the log.

The log is so small that I can upload it here:

```
[10:01:32] [main/INFO]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[10:01:32] [main/INFO]: Using primary tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[10:01:32] [main/INFO]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[10:01:32] [main/INFO]: Forge Mod Loader version 11.15.1.1722 for Minecraft 1.8.9 loading
[10:01:32] [main/INFO]: Java is OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_265, running on Linux:amd64:5.4.0-42-generic, installed at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
[10:01:32] [main/INFO]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[10:01:32] [main/INFO]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker
[10:01:32] [main/INFO]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[10:01:32] [main/INFO]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[10:01:32] [main/INFO]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[10:01:34] [main/INFO]: Found valid fingerprint for Minecraft. Certificate fingerprint cd99959656f753dc28d863b46769f7f8fbaefcfc
[10:01:34] [main/ERROR]: FML appears to be missing any signature data. This is not a good thing
[10:01:34] [main/INFO]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[10:01:34] [main/INFO]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker
[10:01:34] [main/INFO]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.TerminalTweaker
[10:01:34] [main/INFO]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.TerminalTweaker
[10:01:34] [main/INFO]: Launching wrapped minecraft {net.minecraft.client.main.Main}
[10:01:34] [main/ERROR]: Unable to launch
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
Caused by: java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadAssistiveTechnologies(Toolkit.java:807) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:886) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at org.lwjgl.LinuxSysImplementation.<clinit>(LinuxSysImplementation.java:50) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.createImplementation(Sys.java:131) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:116) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71386_F(Minecraft.java:2756) ~[ave.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:41) ~[Main.class:?]
    ... 6 more
[10:01:34] [main/INFO]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]: net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.FMLSecurityManager$ExitTrappedException
[10:01:34] [main/INFO]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.FMLSecurityManager.checkPermission(FMLSecurityManager.java:30)
[10:01:34] [main/INFO]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkExit(SecurityManager.java:761)
[10:01:34] [main/INFO]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:     at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:107)
[10:01:34] [main/INFO]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:     at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:973)
[10:01:34] [main/INFO]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:     at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:138)
[10:01:34] [main/INFO]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:     at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
```

Does anybody have any clue what's happening? I'll greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I should look this up before posting.

I found a [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695560/assistive-technology-not-found-awterror) that fixed the problem for Forge. The first response in that post explains everything.

The only thing to fix now is vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: No I didn't, at least on Ubuntu. It worked flawlessly on PopOS.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to make it work.
You have to have java 8 on your pc and not a single other version, or conflicts may appear.
Then, you have to completely clear your pc of any minecraft related file (I just deleted .minecraft on my personal folder, and uninstalled the game on the ubuntu software store).
Then I dowloaded the game again and then run it with these commands:

```
wget https://launcher.mojang.com/download/Minecraft.tar.gz
tar -xvf Minecraft.tar.gz
cd minecraft-launcher
./minecraft-launcher
```

this made the game reinstall everything again (suposing you deleted everything beforehand), and it should work, worked for me ubuntu 20LTS.

Sorry for any grammar mistakes.