# OpenJDK 8 or 9?

Tags: software-installation

After issuing `apt-cache search jdk`, I see both `openjdk-8-jdk` and `openjdk-9-jdk` listed. I am unsure which one I should install.

I took a look at SDK downloads from Oracle's website below, and I wasn't able to immediately find SDK 9. Why would this be the case?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are planning to install NetBeans then install openjdk-8-jdk because openjdk-9-jdk is not compatible with NetBeans from the default Ubuntu repositories, at least it is not compatible with NetBeans in Ubuntu 16.04. The version of NetBeans in 16.04 is NetBeans 8 which targets Java 8 as its compatible Java version. NetBeans from the default Ubuntu 18.04 and later repositories, is  compatible with openjdk-11-jdk.

Another alternative is to install both openjdk-8-jdk and openjdk-9-jdk and use either `update-alternatives --config java` (update-alternatives is provided by default by dpkg in Ubuntu) or `update-java-alternatives` (which is installed when openjdk-8-jdk is installed) to manually choose which Java to use before running an application. See [update-java-alternatives vs update-alternatives --config java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315646/update-java-alternatives-vs-update-alternatives-config-java).

Answer (score 3):

Java 9 is still in development. You can find official downloads of it at http://jdk.java.net/9/. Which version you should download is entirely a a question of what you plan to do with it.

Edit:
It has been officially released on 2017 Sep.