# System JDK versus SDKMAN

Tags: java, development, sdk, ubuntu-make, jvm

More than once I've had to go into apt to remove `JDK` > 8 because, at least for the moment, `umake` installs `Netbeans 8` which only runs on `JDK` 8.

I only need `JDK` 8 for `Netbeans`, and that temporarily until `umake` install `NB` 9.  That being said, how can I get the [system](https://askubuntu.com/q/315646/45156) to stay at `JDK` 8 (and maybe even `JVM` 8?) in concert with `SDKMAN`?

Or, fundamentally, are these different systems -- Java versioning specific to a user account for `SDKMAN` versus the system configuration?

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ javac -version
javac 11.0.1
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sdk ls java
================================================================================
Available Java Versions
================================================================================
     12.ea.20-open                                                              
     11.0.1-zulu                                                                
     11.0.1-open                                                                
     10.0.2-zulu                                                                
     10.0.2-open                                                                
     9.0.7-zulu                                                                 
     9.0.4-open                                                                 
   * 8.0.192-zulu                                                               
     8.0.191-oracle                                                             
     7.0.201-zulu                                                               
     6.0.119-zulu                                                               
     1.0.0-rc-10-grl                                                            
     1.0.0-rc-9-grl                                                             
     1.0.0-rc-8-grl                                                             


================================================================================
+ - local version
* - installed
> - currently in use
================================================================================
thufir@dur:~$
```

Not sure what happened to `JDK` 8:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.1+13-Ubuntu-2ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.1+13-Ubuntu-2ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing)
thufir@dur:~$
```

fixed [for](https://askubuntu.com/a/388693/45156) now:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
There are 2 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                          Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1111      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac    1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-0ubuntu0.18.10.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_191
thufir@dur:~$
```

but it's getting repetitive.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: why does `java` and `javac` version keep changing?  only because apt is pulling in new packages?