# Java path setting in the ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, maven-3

I have tried to set java path many times by choosing all the combination of paths (among many other combinations too).

Ex :

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

Please help me to set the path.

Comment: What is the $JAVA_HOME output?

Comment: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java

Comment: Hi, could you please clarify your question a bit. What are you trying to achieve, what errors do you get? E.g., do you want to start Maven with a certain java version, do you want Maven to use a specific compiler version, which Java versions did you install.

Comment: If this is just about which JRE/JDK version to use system-wide, check out this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/315646/update-java-alternatives-vs-update-alternatives-config-java/388693#388693

Comment: I want to run Maven. but I'm getting path is not set.

The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE