# JavaFX is missing in Oracle JDK

Tags: software-installation, jdk, javafx

I have installed **Oracle JDK 12** from [ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising](http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu) but when I create **Java FX** project in **Intellij Idea** it says **Java FX** is not configured in selected **JDK**. Seems the **JDK** doesn't include **Java FX** although it must be ([Oracle web-site](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html) says JDK 12 includes Java FX).

How to install **Java FX** for **Oracle JDK 12**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has removed JavaFX from the JDK with Version 11.

As far as I know, the latest Open Java FX Version in Ubuntu is 11. So if you want to work with version 12, you'll have to install it manually. That should be no problem though. Check out the official tutorial:

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx

Otherwise, if you are on at least Ubuntu 18.04, you should be able to install OpenJDK 11 and Open JFX 11 with your package manager (might have to enable the Universe repository).

Comment: Sorry, can you advice me what should I use for GUI then? Honestly, I just wanted to create GUI project in Java and Java FX looked more perspective than Swing.

Comment: JavaFX is still a great choice for UIs in Java! They just moved it out of the core JDK so it's "leaner" and they can be developed faster. I would either A) install both dependencies via the package manager and either remove JDK 12 or at least make sure to [set the default JDK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315646/update-java-alternatives-vs-update-alternatives-config-java/388693#388693) B) install JavaFX 12 like the tutorial says!
It depends what you need and what you want to do. But FYI, Java 11 is a Long Term Support version, 12 is a short lived one...