# No .jinfo file. Adding Openjdk 16.0.2 to update-java-alternatives

Tags: software-installation, java, openjdk, jdk

I want to add /opt/jdk-16.0.2 to update-java-alternatives, but there is no .jinfo file. File should be there, because I have openjdk 16.0.2

I had no problems with adding java to update-alternatives java command, but I don't want to do it with every java-related binary.

I installed openjdk by extracting it from archive and changing JAVA_HOME to /opt/jdk-16.0.2 Should I do something more? Can I generate .jinfo file?

I'd like to use update-java-alternatives to switch between Java versions. I don't want to play with scripts and update-alternatives java

https://askubuntu.com/a/388693

> update-java-alternatives requires presence of a file with extension
> .jinfo in directory /usr/lib/jvm. The opendjk package is shipped with
> a .jinfo file, the jdk of Oracle (formerly Sun) is not. As
> alternative, you configure alternatives without
> update-java-alternatives:

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Why do you not want to use official deb-packages which [provide this file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=jinfo)?

Comment: Because I want to use newer version of JDK

Comment: I used oracle jdk installer from https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/java